# Graph API via Facebook (Android SDK)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

This is a two part question.

1: Why do I need the user's access token to get the graph object for a public url? Why isn't the facebook app's id sufficient?

2: When requesting the number of likes on a url, including share count and comments, I am only getting the number of shares and comments and not the number of likes. the code being used is as below

```
new GraphRequest().newGraphPathRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "http://cnn.com/",
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            JSONObject graphResponseJSON = response.getJSONObject();
            Log.i(TAG, "FACEBOOK GRAPH RESPONSE: " + graphResponseJSON);
        }
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

What should I do to get the number of likes for a url?

Comment: 1. Try to use an app access token.

Answer (score 0):

As `@WizKid` suggested, we can use app's access token to perform such operations.

**eg:**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("access_token", "facebook_app_id|facebook_app_secret");
        params.putBoolean("summary", true);
        new GraphRequest(
                null,
                "/" + objectId + "/likes",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "FACEBOOK GRAPH RESPONSE FOR LIKES: " + response);
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Here `facebook_app_id` and `facebook_app_secret` are to be replaced with their relevant values.

It's **important** to NOT directly paste the values in the code as it can be decompiled and the key's can be recovered by any third party.
Rather store it in strings.xml or preferably server side.